# Python Asyncio TimoutError is not using builtin TimeoutError as base class

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, base-class, timeoutexception

Why is `asyncio` not using the builtin `TimeoutError` as base class?

Instead of writing

```py
try:
    await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.sleep(10), timeout=5)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    pass
```

one could write

```py
try:
    await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.sleep(10), timeout=5)
except TimeoutError:
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why they made a separate `asyncio.TimeoutError` that was distinct from the plain `TimeoutError` in earlier versions of Python, but you may be glad to know that as of Python 3.11, the asyncio-specific `asyncio.TimeoutError` class has been removed, and replaced with a reference to the plain `TimeoutError`. That is, as of Python 3.11, `asyncio.TimeoutError is TimeoutError` evaluates to `True`, and any `except TimeoutError` clause will function exactly the same as any `except asyncio.TimeoutError` clause, and so forth. You can even test this yourself:

```py
# THIS ONLY WORKS IN Python 3.11 AND ABOVE
import asyncio

# prints True
print(asyncio.TimeoutError is TimeoutError)

# prints "caught"
try:
    raise TimeoutError("")
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    print("caught")

# prints "also caught"
try:
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError("")
except TimeoutError:
    print("also caught")
```

In Python 3.11+, we can see where `asyncio.TimeoutError` is defined as an alias for `TimeoutError` in `asyncio/exceptions.py`, on line 14:

```py
"""asyncio exceptions."""


__all__ = ('BrokenBarrierError',
           'CancelledError', 'InvalidStateError', 'TimeoutError',
           'IncompleteReadError', 'LimitOverrunError',
           'SendfileNotAvailableError')


class CancelledError(BaseException):
    """The Future or Task was cancelled."""


TimeoutError = TimeoutError  # make local alias for the standard exception

# other exception definitions irrelevant to this question follow...
```

I don't know the Python devs' original rationale for creating an `asyncio.TimeoutError` exception class that is distinct from `TimeoutError`, but I assume they initially felt that the idea of "timing out" in `async` code was sufficiently different from "timing out" in regular synchronous code that there should be a new exception class for asyncio. Subsequently, they must have realized that those two versions of "timing out" aren't different enough to warrant an asyncio-specific `TimeoutError`, so refactored the class to be an alias instead.